# add own variable in json each function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, append

I have a code where this portion will append into a table, I need to increment my serial number by 1 for each response. All I am getting in the console is `NaN`.

```js
var qi = 1;
$.each(JSON.parse(resp), function(key, value) {
  if (value.stock_type == "hardware") {
    var s_type = 0;
  } else {
    var s_type = 1;
  }

  $("#emp-tbody")
    .append('<tr role="row">' +
      '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkRow"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock_type[]" value="' + s_type + '" disabled>' + value.stock_type + '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock_type_value[]" value="' + value.master_stock_id + '" disabled>' + value.stock_name + '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock_model_number[]" value="' + value.product_model_id + '" disabled>' + value.product_model_id + '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock_model_serial_number_' + qi + '[]" value="' + value.product_serial_id + '" disabled>' + value.product_serial_id + '</td>' +
      '<td><select class="form-control masterslist this_warranty"  name="stock_warrenty[]" style="font-size: 15px;" disabled>' +
      '<option></option>' +
      '<option value="1">1</option>' +
      '<option value="2">2</option>' +
      '<option value="3">3</option>' +
      '<option value="4">4</option>' +
      '<option value="5">5</option>' +
      '</select></td>' +
      '<td><input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[]" value="' + value.qty_issue + '" disabled>' + value.qty_issue + '</td>' +
      '</tr>');
  var qi = qi + 1;
  console.log(qi);
});
```

Comment: You're redefining `qi` within the loop. Remove `var` there, eg. `qi = qi + 1;` or just `qi++`.

Comment: The NaN property represents "Not-a-Number" value. This property indicates that a value is not a legal number.

Tip: Use the isNaN() global function to check if a value is a NaN value.

Comment: thts worked, thx though